# NoSQL for multiple simultaneous connections

Tags: nosql

Which database NoSQL is recommended for web service with multiple simultaneous connections?

Comment: Why are you tagging the question as MySql and Sql if you are asking to recomend a NoSQL data base??? It is  so easy to tag correctly ....

Comment: I just want to be more comprehensive, sorry!

Comment: Hmm, "all of them", hopefully, all modern database (SQL & NoSQL) will allow you to have many connections. You should look too the best database/database model that suits your needs